# Images appear in backend but not in frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, images

I've installed and removed the JomSEF plugin for redirecting.

Now I've a problem. When I create an article, in TinyMCE I insert images and I can see it in the article. When I publish it, images disappear and I can't see them.

If I check the source of the page, I can see the correct path for images, likes `images\articles\001.png` and `images` is the folder where I stored it.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities I can think of:

- Installing the extension has changed the base tag.  View the source and make sure this is still pointing to the site root, so that relative links to images/ are still correct.
- The extension contained multiple elements - plugins, componenents etc, and you have not uninstalled all of them. Do an audit of your extensions and remove any by that developer.

Looking further into this, out-of-the-box the base tag will just be the page you are on and the link generated (when the page has been rendered) `/images` rather than `images`. With this structure, a fawlty base tag would not break it - images should be loading from the site root.

Comment: How can I check the base tag? Which source should I check?

Comment: The source of the page showing the broken image.  I've updated my answer with some doubt as to if this is the cause, however.   That said, images\articles\001.png is going to be a problematic URL and \images\articles\001.png the expected one.  Can you confirm that the beginning \ is definitely not there?

Comment: Yes, I can see `<img style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; display: block;" alt="" src="images/articles/gis/postgisqgis-001.png">` in the source file and `><img style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; display: block;" src="images/articles/gis/postgisqgis-001.png" alt="" />` in the source of the article in TinyMCE.

Comment: Is System - SEF turned on?  That seems to be the core plugin that makes the image URLs start from the root instead.

Comment: I don't have system - SEF anymore, I've uninstalled it. Maybe I should install it again?

Comment: Yes, I reckon that should fix it.  Surprised Joomla allows you to uninstall that one.  The alternative would be to change your base tag so it always points to your site root, but keeping things as out-of-the-box as possible is usually sensible.

Comment: The plugin had messed up everything. I've taken a backup and restored a previous version. I'm not so smart yet to fix these kind of problems...

Comment: I find it odd that a SEF extension would screw up the path of an image. It's a relative path pointing to a directory. Check the `<base>` in the source code and also check the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Lodder - Pretty sure it is the core System - SEF plugin being removed and that the third party extension was a red herring.